# Button not clickable in custom LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have a custom view that contain a framelayout. This framelayout contain two views (LinearLayout) that can be swipe. If I swipe the first one, the second one appears and vice versa. One of those views has a button but I don't know why, this button is like disable. I cannot click on it and the onClick method has no effect.

Here the structure of the layout xml inflated in the custom view :

```
<FrameLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/frontview"
  /> 
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/backview">
    <Button
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/ButtonUpdate"
       android:text="@string/bUpdate"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:clickable="true"
       style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        />
  </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here the code in my custom view :

```
public class mView extends LinearLayout {

ImageView icon;
TextView current_data;
TextView previous_data;
TextView time ;
Button bUpdate;
EditText TextUpdate;

public mView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public mView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
    init(context);

}

public mView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    // nothing
    }
}

public void init(Context pContext) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) pContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View ll = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_data, this, true);

    /** We initialize the elements of our UI **/
    /**
     * First View
     */
    icon= (ImageView) ll.findViewById(R.id.ic_icon);
    current_data = ll.(TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_data);
    previous_data = ll.(TextView) findViewById(R.id.previous_data);
    time = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.time);

    /**
     * Second View
     */
    bUpdate = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.ButtonUpdate);
    TextUpdate= (EditText) ll.findViewById(R.id.TextUpdate);
    bUpdate.setOnClickListener(new bUpdateClickListener());        
}

private class bUpdateClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // When the button is clicked, the front view re-appears and the backview disappears
        frontview
                .animate()
                .translationX(0);
        backview
                .animate()
                .translationX(-backview.getMeasuredWidth());

    }
}
```

The swipe is correctly handle with `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` and `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`.

Here the main.xml used in MyActivity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#ffffff">

   <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#f6f6f6">

      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/infoimc"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         android:text="@string/app_name"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:textSize="16dp"/>
      <View
         android:id="@+id/divider_infoimc"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:background="#99CC00"/>
      <com.example.essai.CustomGraph
         android:id="@+id/CustomGraph"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="200dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:visibility="visible"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

   </LinearLayout>

   <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical">

   <com.example.essai.mView
      android:id="@+id/CustomView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And MyActivity.class :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }

}
```

I don't know if the button must be handle also in the Activity ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The root cause

According to [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html):

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
>   a **single** item.

If there is more items, like in your case, then "unexpected" things will happen:

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child
>   on top.

This means, your `frontview` is on top of your `backview` and since the `frontview` doesn't have `android:clickable="true"` the click events (on button) are not delegated below.

### Solution 1

**Reorder the child-layout gravity programmatically.**

> You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control
>   their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each
>   child, using the `android:layout_gravity` attribute.

Just switch the `android:layout_gravity="top"` and `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` whenever you are sliding them.

### Solution 2

**Control the visibility of the child-layouts programmatically.**

When the `backview` should be displayed, set the visibility of the `frontview` to `View.GONE`. And set it to `View.VISIBLE` in the reversed case.

### Solution 3

**Change `FrameLayout` to a different layout type.**

Could require more "fiddling" with layout xmls...

See what you're familliar with the most and choose the solution accordingly :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the first solution by adding programmatically `android:layout_gravity="top` and `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` in `init()` but it doesn't work. So I put the backview in top of the framelayout and I set the visibility of the frontview to GONE but the result is similar, the button is disable :( Actually, I want something like in Gmail. After swipe the first view, a second is available to perform some action. In my case, I have an EditText and a Button.

Comment: After a few tries with first solution (unsuccessful), I decided to try the second solution and finally I think the issue is in my manner to handle the swipe.

Comment: That's what I wanted to suggest -- to post the code where you swipe the views. If the solution worked for you, the usual procedure is to accept it :)